# Android Studio not opening JDK works fine

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-6

After installing JDK and Setting Environment Variables I installed Android Studio. However, after install when I open it it only shows the image below:

### [image]

For endless time. `javac` works fine in `cmd`. Studio was working fine previously .

Comment: you will have to provide more details. what version of jdk? what version of studio? what environment? what is the error message? you mentioned android studio was working fine before. so did you install jdk or update a jdk?

Comment: JDK -10.0.1, Android Studio - 3.1.3,  Windows 8.1, No error Message just loading and loading showing screen as per given image above, problem occurring after format of Windows 8.1 (reinstall), downloaded JDK

Comment: I had some problem with openjdk 10 and intellij idea. It was more to do with license check, which might not be case for android studio. Using oracle jdk solved the issue. Openjdk does not come with full cacerts.

Comment: me too using oracle JDK

Answer (score 1):

I found Solution 
as I told above that i had reinstalled Windows 8.1 OS I had selected Hindi language as input method language and that was the problem because Android Studio required some time stamps and number in my case those letters were in Hindi so there was a mismatch while opening Android Studio so by change Language to English Solved Problem